# Sed failing with escape characters in variables

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

sed terminating early because of escape characters in variables. Hoping awk can do what I need but can't see how!

```
# Main section ==========================================╕
LASTIP=`grep -E '[0-2]{0,1}[0-9]{0,9}[0-9]{0,1}\.[0-2]{0,1}[0-9]{0,9}[0-9]{0,1}\.[0-2]{0,1}[0-9]{0,9}[0-9]{0,1}\.[0-2]{0,1}[0-9]{0,9}[0-9]{0,1}' $SRCDIR/$IPLOGFILE | tail -1|awk -F'\t' '{print$3}'`
if [ "$CURRENTIP" == "$LASTIP" ]; then
# Still using old IP===================================╕
  FIRSTDETECTED=`grep $LASTIP $SRCDIR/$IPLOGFILE | tail -1|awk -F'\t' '{print$1}'`
  LASTDETECTED=`grep $LASTIP $SRCDIR/$IPLOGFILE | tail -1|awk -F'\t' '{print$2}'`
  OLDLINE=$(printf "$FORMAT" "$FIRSTDETECTED" "$LASTDETECTED" "$LASTIP")
  AMENDEDLINE=$(printf "$FORMAT" "$FIRSTDETECTED" "$TIMESTAMP" "$LASTIP")
  sed -i "s/'$OLDLINE'/'$AMENDEDLINE'/g" $SRCDIR/$IPLOGFILE
```

This works fine apart from the last sed, which terminates because `$OLDLINE` and/or `$AMENDEDLINE` contains escape chars. I thought I could do a direct substitution for awk to solve the issue but the more I thought about it the more I thought the whole section could be done much more efficiently with awk - maybe in one line of awk? Trouble is I don't know where to start. Am I fooling myself about simplifying it or is there a way? If there is, you may have to help me out, as I find this stuff 'warps my fragile little mind'*

*courtesy of Cartman ;P

I've snipped out the section but can supply the rest of the script if that helps?

Comment: As a workaround, I've tried the following two lines instead of the last sed
    `#sed -i "s/'$OLDLINE'/'$AMENDEDLINE'/g" $SRCDIR/$IPLOGFILE`

    `sed -i "$ d" $SRCDIR/$IPLOGFILE`

    `printf "$FORMAT" "$FIRSTDETECTED" "$TIMESTAMP" "$LASTIP" >> $SRCDIR/$IPLOGFILE`

Comment: "snipped out the section but can supply the rest" .. Please read about [Minimal,Complete,Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) We want to see the minimal code that produces the problem, not the whole "War and Peace" tome ;-). Often times when you strip your problem down to the basics, you'll find the solution yourself. Good luck.

Comment: I take your point generally but I'm asking if a single awk can substitute for the grep that delivers LASTIP, the IF condition, the greps that deliver FIRSTDETECTED & LASTDETECTED and finally the sed that updates the latest timestamp in the file. I can't see a way to 'reproduce' the problem without showing the context. OK, so I could have stripped the few echos/printfs I used to try to debug. I'll edit those out now ;)

Comment: The (tab delimited) file being queried contains a timestamp for when an IP was first detected, another for when it was last detected and the IP address

Comment: Whatever it is you're trying to do will be trivial in awk, but edit your question to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output (i.e. the missing parts of a [mcve]) so we can help you.

Comment: I couldn't think how to distil it down to what you're asking for. I guess I'll just delete the question

Comment: Let me see if I can rephrase this in more abstract terms:

I have a tab delimited file containing a timestamp for when my IP was first detected, another for when it was last detected and the IP itself. I periodically run a bash script that gets the latest IP. I want to use awk to test the last line in the file and if the IP detected there is the same as the current IP, update the latest timestamp but if it isn't the same IP, append a new line to the file with two NOW timestamps and the latest IP.

Comment: @Greg : please update your Q with 3 lines of data, just as it should be in your file, and then 1 change/update record and 1 add record. WIthout seeing the data you're working with, we have to play 20 questions about why it isn't working ;-) .OK? Also, please include code for what populates `$CURRENTIP`. And please reply to 2 L's shellter ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps try like that

```
sed -i 's/'"$OLDLINE"'/'"$AMENDEDLINE"'/g' "$SRCDIR"/"$IPLOGFILE"
```

I think '$OLDLINE' and '$AMENDEDLINE' are not expanded